# find un-parseable xml strings using tsql (sql server 2005)

Tags: t-sql

Having a nvarchar column containing xml. Is there an easy way to find those rows where:

```
CONVERT(xml, XML, 2)
```

does not work? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What would do the job is [TRY_CONVERT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh230993%28v=sql.110%29.aspx), but that's new in SQL 2012.

So, pre 2012, the only other way I can think of is to create a SQLCLR function to try parsing the value into a XML blob.